# Download until certain point has been reached in Python

Tags: python, sockets, urllib2

I'm making a Python script that verifies if a Wikipedia link chain is valid. For instance, the chain

```
List of jōyō kanji > Elementary schools in Japan > Education > Knowledge
```

is a valid one since you can reach each page only by clicking links.

The issue here is that these pages are really long and downloading the entire page, checking if the link is in the page and repeating all the steps will take a long time. And the chains could be longer too.

So what I want to know is if I can use `urllib2` (or any other library) to download each page and tell it to stop when needed or if this would just put more load on the CPU and make things worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way of doing this with urllib2, but there's one obvious solution using raw sockets:

```
import urlparse

def found(text, data):
     # return True if text was found in data

def get_title(url):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    host = parsed_url.netloc
    path = parsed_url.path
    port = 80

    web = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        web.connect((host, port))
    except Exception:
        return

    web.send('GET %s HTTP/1.1\n' % path)
    web.send('Host: %s\n' % host)
    web.send('\n')

    done = False
    while not done:
        data = web.recv(2048)
        if len(data) > 0 and found("text", data):
            web.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            web.close()
            title = title_match.group(1)
            done = True

    # Do something
```

This way you stop downloading once you find the relevant data and avoid downloading unnecessary content from large web pages.

Answer (score 1):

Why repeat the steps. You should be able to do them in parallel, since each step should be independent of each other.

Comment: I know I didn't make this clear, and it's my fault, but I'm going to use a slow Internet connection for this (256Kbps). Also, are you saying this could make use of threads or did I misunderstand?

Comment: yes, use multiple threads.. so that you dont eat up your cpu cycle waiting on a network response which could take a lot of cycles.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess I'll do this, but I'd like to know if doing what I wanted is possible or not. Maybe I need to use raw sockets?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a [static snapshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) from Wikipedia.

Comment: What if I want to do the same with something that's not Wikipedia? And I don't think I have any space left for a static snapshot.